# Programmatically activate @EnableConfigurationProperties from ApplicationContextRunner

Tags: spring-boot

I want to use `ApplicationContextRunner` for asserts on beans existence based on `@ConditionalProperty` I've got in `SomeConfig`. The problem is that `SomeProperties` is defunct with all prop values as null, because conf properties are not activated. There is no direct access to `EnableConfigurationPropertiesRegistrar` which is `@Import` by annotation `@EnableConfigurationProperties` :

```
contextRunner = new ApplicationContextRunner().withInitializer(applicationContext -> applicationContext.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("test"))
                                              .withInitializer(new ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer())
                                              .withBean(SomeProperties.class)
                                              .withConfiguration(UserConfigurations.of(SomeConfig.class));
```

The block above will have `SomeProperties` content props as null during run.

How can I activate programmatically conf properties?

I need top code block to do exactly same as :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class, classes = {SomeConfig.class, SomeProperties.class})
public class SomeTest
```

I could use `withProperties`, but my properties are `@Validated`, so they will blow up if I declare just the one for `@ConditionalOnProperty` same time I don't want to load manually entire list of properties by hand.

Answer (score 3):

Finally solved:

```
 .withUserConfiguration(SomeConfig.class, ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class);
```

It is always AutoConfiguration classes making the magic, my bad forgot it.